# Generic regex with format specific conditions

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, generics, web-scraping

Can anyone help me with a **generic** regex (in Visual Basic) that can handle below formats?

```
2100
2.100
2,100
2 100
2  100 (double white-spaces between "2" and "1"
10100
10.100
10,100
10 100
10  100
```

The Regex shall match all numbers in above formats not only the 2100 and 10100 examples.

b) also a generic Regex that matched above but **dont** match formats:

```
2.10
2,10
2.1
2,1
10.1
10,1
10.10
10,10
```

The regex I have tried but wont work is:

```
Regex(\d+(?:[,.]| {1,2})\d+$)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you just replace the space, comma and the dot for nothing ?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. I shall grab/find these formats in my posting from a webpage and therefore I need a regex that "match" these formats and dont match those formats under my b) posting

Comment: @jorge campos: maybe it can solve my question just to replace the .,blankspaces with nothing. But the problem will then be for 2.10 or 10.10, these will then be 210 and 1010 and thats not what I'm aming for. The number the regex shall match shall be minimum 1000. Any code recommendation?

Comment: So the only way to differ 2.10 from 2.100 is the two zeros at left? Because even in a regex it will be little difficult to differ theese numbers, unless you have it as a rule, like three numbers is 'thousand' and two numbers is a number with decimals... My english is not so good I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^\d+(([.,]|\s{1,2})\d+)?$
```

Notice `^` and `(([.,]|\s{1,2})\d+)` which I made it optional with a `?`

Comment: thanks but when I try: regex(\d+(([.,]|\s{1,2})\d+)?$) I still get match of "2,10"... (?)

Comment: @user3214294 Do you want to match `100` after the first matches?